# Как разделить строки в списке Python?

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

Мне нужно спарсить таблицу с помощью BeautifulSoup, на на выходе получаю лист с неразделенными строками, и я не знаю как мне их правильно разделить.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import requests

url = 'https://www.iqair.com/ru/kyrgyzstan/bishkek'

def get_weather(url):
    response = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response, 'lxml')
    weather = []
    weather_ = soup.find_all('div', class_='weather__detail')
    for i in weather_:
        row = ''
        rows = i.find_all ('tr')
        for row in rows:
            if (row.text.find ("Погода") > -1):
                weather.append(row.text)
            elif (row.text.find ("Температура") > -1):
                weather.append(row.text)
            elif (row.text.find ("Влажность") > -1):
                weather.append(row.text)
            elif (row.text.find ("Ветер") > -1):
                weather.append(row.text)
            elif(row.text.find ("Давление") > -1):
                weather.append(row.text)                      
    return weather

get_weather(url)
```

На выходе я получаю:

[image: лист]

Мне нужно:

["Погода", "Сильная облачность",
"Температура", "0°C",
"Влажность", "58%",
"Ветер", "3.2 mp/h",
"Давление", "1024 mb"]

Буду признателен любой помощи, и, если возможно, посоветуйте пожалуйста другой способ парсинга отдельных элементов таблиц.

Comment: Вы в вопросе привел все что можно, кроме того, что нужно. Приведите список, который вы получаете в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: В row у вас попадает строка таблицы, а вам по идее нужны отдельные ячейки (окруженные тегами td). Вы берете текст строки таблицы целиком с вырезанными тегами, из-за этого все склеивается.

Comment: @strawdog Я прикрепил фото списка

Comment: "в воспроизводимом виде". нам ваш список с фото перепечатывать вручную, чтобы пример воспроизвести?

Comment: Спасибо вам всем за помощь! Я реально тупанул, делал все сонный и не хотел нормально думать ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Можно так сделать

```
def get_weather(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text, 'lxml')
    weather = []
    table = soup.find('div', class_='weather__detail').find('table')
    for row in table.find_all('tr'):
        for col in row.find_all('td'):
            weather.append(col.text)
    return weather
```

Можно вложенный цикл заменить на генератор:

```
def get_weather(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup (response.text, 'lxml')
    table = soup.find('div', class_='weather__detail').find('table')
    weather = [col.text for row in table.find_all('tr') for col in row.find_all('td')]
    return weather
```

И рубрика "никогда так не делай" (однострочник):

```
def get_weather(url):
    return [col.text for row in BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml').find('div', class_='weather__detail').find('table').find_all('tr') for col in row.find_all('td')]
```